# Python speed up list of dict iteration

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to speed up the the creation of this list. Its taking around 5 seconds which is a little bit too long. The bottle neck is in the variants section at the bottom.

products and variants are both peewee query's and is a one to many relationship.

If seems like there should be a better way to iterate to find the correct variants.

```
data = [{
    'product_id': product.id,
    'title': product.title,
    'price': product.price,
    'variants': [{'product_variant_id': v.id,
                    'colour': v.colour}
                    for v in variants if v.product_id == product.id]
} for product in products]
```

Comment: Create a dictionary mapping product ids to variants so that you don't have to iterate over all variants for each product.

Comment: I endorse the last comment, you traverse all `variants` every time, leading to somewhat quadratic time. You could either use something like `itertools.groupby` before, or, better yet, do as much as possible directly in the data base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user3760780 commented, create a mapping from product ids to variants to avoid repeated iteration of variants:

```
products = {v.product_id: v for v in variants }
```

Then, you list comprehension can be more efficient:

```
data = [{
    'product_id': product.id,
    'title': product.title,
    'price': product.price,
    'variants': [{'product_variant_id': products[product.id].id,
                    'colour': products[product.id].colour}]
} for product in products]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to change it slightly but got me going in the right direction.